# Conditional relations with doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have need to create this database scheme in Symfony Entities :

ClassA:

- id
- name
- ... some other attributes only for class A

ClassB:

- id
- name
- ... some other attributes only for class B

ClassC:

- id
- name
- ... some other attributes only for class C

Course:

- id
- name
- type
- class_id
- class_type [A, B, C]
- ...

I need to create relations between Course Entity (using the class_id) with the other entities (ClassA, ClassB, ClassC) (using the id) and using the class_type (A, B, C).

A Course is not a class and a class is not a course. There is no inheritance here. In my project I'm using this concept (id and type to map different entities). So I need to solve this problem with a simple example like this one

I thought about using @ORM\DiscriminationMap here:

```
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Course")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="course_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"A" = "ClassA", "B" = "ClassB", "C" = "ClassC"})
 */
abstract class Course
{
 //...
}

class ClassA extends Course
{
 //...
}

class ClassB extends Course
{
 //...
}

class ClassC extends Course
{
 //...
}
```

Or something like this.

But I don't want to copy the Course's attributes in the ClassA, ClassB, ClassC entities because "extends" will copy the parent entity's attributes to the child.

It's not about inheritence. I need to keep the database scheme described above without adding any additional attributes from the other entities.

Thank you

Comment: So as i understand you need relation between `Class(A|B|C)` and `Course` ? is it two different database tables right?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes they are 4 entities (database tables). The relation should be based on the Course.class_type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution might be next:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="class")
     * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string", length=20)
     * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
     *     "class_a" = "ClassA",
     *     "class_b" = "ClassB",
     *     "class_c" = "ClassC"
     * })
     */
    abstract class AbstractClass
    {
       ... common fields
        /**
         * @var PersistentCollection
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Course", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="course")
         */
        protected $courses;

    }
   /**
    * @Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="class_a")
    */
    class ClassA extends AbstractClass
    {
     //...
    }
   /**
    * @Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="class_b")
    */
    class ClassB extends AbstractClass
    {
     //...
    }
   /**
    * @Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="class_c")
    */
    class ClassC extends AbstractClass
    {
     //...
    }

   /**
    * @Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="course")
    */
    class Course
    {

        /**
         * @var AbstractClass
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AbstractClass", inversedBy="course")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
         */
        private $course;
        ....

    }
```

So now you'll have single table for all your `classes` with one to many relation to `course`(this is just an example, you could use one to many or many to many, depends on your needs).

Within DQL you can find out which class is used with [INSTANCE OF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#query-the-type).

Comment: This will add an extra column "type" wish specifie the class type (A,B or C)

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your response. I tried it as you said and it's a good idea that I have never thinked about. But I realized that when I add the annotation "@ORM\Table" and "@ORM\Entity" before the classes ClassA, ClassB and ClassC then I add to each Class(A,B,C) its specific attributes I find 2 problems: As you said there is only the AbstractClass that will be saved as a database table and the second problem is that the classes attributes will be added to the Course table. I only need that each class has its attribute in a different table not together

Comment: This worked fine Thank you very much. I add some changes: add the annotation "@ORM\Table" and "@ORM\Entity" before the classes ClassA, ClassB and ClassC. And replace "@ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")" by "@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")" to have the additional attributes of each Class(A,B,C) in its database table. Thank you you saved my project

Comment: @MohamedAymenKarmous nice!